# how to calculate vertices position of b2Polygon in box2D?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, vertices

I have one shape when it touches another collision detection should happen, for that i need to draw b2Polygon shape in xcode. I need proper vertices to draw this shape in iPhone. Can anyone please help me how to do that?

Thank you,

Anks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I have an image which collides with other image. I can not just give that image shape as circle. I need specific shape for that i need co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is debug draw in box2d. See any example of box2d testbed coming with cocos2d. That's if you want your b2Shapes to be drawn.